# Unity does not start automatically, have to start it manually

Tags: unity, upgrade, startup

After upgrading to 12.04 the system starts up normally, and shows me the login screen.

After I log in, unity does not seem to start up and shows me a small XTerm window.

I start unity manually from there by typing into the command. The xterm window stays open and if I close it it takes me back to the login screen. The theme also seems to be totally messed up. Other than that every thing seems to be working...

I have also reinstalled the ubuntu-desktop package several times, does not seem to help

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you give some details on your set up, ATI/Nvidia? Laptop/Desktop?

Comment: I was logging in in recovery mode all the time! What an idiot! I just changed the little icon above the user/pass field from Recovery to normal and it fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I was logging in in recovery mode all the time! What an idiot! I just changed the little icon above the user/pass field from Recovery to normal and it fixed it!